# Auto role when someone starts streaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wanted to set a role for a user if he/she starts streaming and sending a message in #streaming. But I keep getting this error that `TypeError: Cannot read 'add' of undefined.`

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const guild = newMember.guild;
    const streamingRole = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 'streamer');
    if (newMember.user.bot) return;
    if (newMember.user.presence.activities.streaming) { // Started playing.
        let announcement = `Ebrywan ${newMember} just started streaming`;
        let channelID = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === "streaming");
        if (channelID) channelID.send(announcement);
        newMember.roles.add(streamingRole)
        console.log(`${streamingRole.name} added to ${newMember.user.tag}`)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can see from the documentation newMember is a Presence and not a user you can add a role too. Try:

```
newMember.member.roles.add(streamingRole)
```

.member will give you the member and you can get the roles of a member + adding new roles should also be possible

Presence: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence
Member: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember